# Error after migrating to Vite: Error: Failed to resolve entry for package "bulma"

Tags: vue.js, sass, vite, bulma

## Background

I have been migrating a Vue 2.7.14 app to Vite, but I have been unable to build the Docker image due to an error with an scss package.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20.5-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json pnpm-lock.yaml /app
RUN apk add --no-cache git \
    && corepack enable \
    && pnpm config set store-dir /app/.pnpm-store \
    && pnpm config set package-import-method copy

FROM base AS prod-deps
RUN pnpm fetch --prod \
    && pnpm install --prefer-offline --ignore-scripts --frozen-lockfile --prod

FROM base AS build
COPY . /app
RUN pnpm fetch \
    && pnpm install --prefer-offline --ignore-scripts --frozen-lockfile \
    && pnpm build

FROM base AS deploy
COPY --from=prod-deps /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/dist /app/dist
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ['/bin/sh', 'start_compose.sh']
```

In `main.ts`, I import a main scss file, which imports other scss files.

### main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from '@/App.vue';
import { useRouter } from '@/router';
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import '@/assets/scss/main.scss';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(Buefy, {
  defaultIconPack: 'mdi',
});

new Vue({
  router: useRouter(),
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

### main.scss

```
/* SCSS manifest file */

/* Bulma utilities */
@import 'bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables';
@import 'bulma/sass/utilities/functions';
...
```

## Problem

When I try to build the image, I run into the following error:

```
476.8 > placemake-website@1.0.11 build /app
476.8 > vite build
476.8 
477.6 vite v4.4.9 building for production...
478.0 transforming...
491.1 file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28691
491.1     throw new Error(`Failed to resolve entry for package "${id}". ` +
491.1           ^
491.1 
491.1 Error: Failed to resolve entry for package "bulma". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
491.1     at packageEntryFailure (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28691:11)
491.1     at resolvePackageEntry (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28688:5)
491.1     at tryNodeResolve (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28419:20)
491.1     at Context.resolveId (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:28180:28)
491.1     at Object.resolveId (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:44207:64)
491.1     at async Object.<anonymous> (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.4.9_sass@1.66.1/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:65837:21)
491.1 
491.1 Node.js v20.5.1
491.2  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

## Question

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you have `bulma` installed? (check `package.json`).

Comment: Yes, `"bulma": "^0.9.4"` is installed as a dependency.

Comment: Does it work if you prefix the urls in the scss file with `~`? (e.g: `@import '~bulma/sass/...'`)

Comment: No, I get an error `[vite:css] [sass] Can't find stylesheet to import.` because I am using vite.